# Can Firefox run Java 8?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, java

I've installed a few openjdk-8-jre packages (including one w/"headless" in its name) but I haven't been able to get it to work in FF. I've seen a lot of other posts over this issue, but they tend to apply to earlier Javas (there is no "libnpjp2.so" for instance). Is it possible? and how?
I'm running Lubuntu 14.04.2 i386.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin to run Java in a browser is called [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page). Currently, IcedTea only has Java 7 releases (the version 2 releases). Java 8 would correspond to a version 3 release, so until there's a version 3 release of IcedTea, you won't be able to run Java 8 in the browser.

Comment: I see. I take it that your answer applies not just to FF but also to Chrome and any other web browser than runs on Ubuntu 14?

Comment: Chrome(ium) dropped support for NPAPI plugins sometime around version 35. Since IcedTea is a NPAPI plugin, and since there isn't any PPAPI plugin for Java (as far as I know), Chrome(ium) on Linux cannot run Java in the browser.